# Fonts are not applying

Tags: css, fonts

In my wordpress site, I need to use another fonts for a table, so I've downloaded it and define it in a `font-face`, but somehow it is not applying and giving an error in console.

**CSS:**

```
    @font-face{
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue Bold";
    src: url("https://halfpanthippo.com/wp-content/themes/halfpanthippo/fonts/Helvetica-Neu-Bold.ttf");
    }
    @font-face{
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue Regular";
    src: url("https://halfpanthippo.com/wp-content/themes/halfpanthippo/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.ttf");
    }
   .pricing-stack .well .title{
     font-family:"Helvetica Neue Regular"; 
    }
```

**Error:**

[image]

Could not figure out what this error is for! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use https from an http site with your CORS policy. Simple solution is to use a relative URL for the fonts in your stylesheet.

Comment: Why not to download font files & load them from own theme path?

Comment: @KhushbuVaghela as JacobPeattie said https when ssl is not active gives problems. Next time, when you in include a file (any kind of files) use relative paths only e.g. /wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/img/ico.png